# Make file error when compiling cpp files from folder A into folder B (no rule to make target xxx.o needed by MyApp))

Tags: makefile

I am setting up a makefile for a small project and am trying to get it to build all the object and binary files to a single output folder. There seems to be an issue when trying to compile cpp files from anywhere other than the folder containing the make file.

Currently I have the following files:

> main.cpp
>
> HelloWorld.cpp
>
> Logger/Logger.cpp

And this is the debug build rule from my makefile:

```
#
# Debug rule
#
debug: $(DEBUG_BINARY)

$(DEBUG_BINARY): $(DEBUG_OBJ_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) -o $(DEBUG_BINARY) $^

$(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

I am attempting to compile to the following folder:

> build/debug/

But this is the output I get:

> g++ -c -I. -DDEBUG -g -o build/debug/HelloWorld.o HelloWorld.cpp
>
> g++ -c -I. -DDEBUG -g -o build/debug/main.o main.cpp
>
> make: *** No rule to make target 'build/debug/Logger.o', needed by 'build/debug/MyApp'. Stop.

Edit:

If I explicitly add a rule for the Logger.cpp file it compiles fine, presumably because the last line using the % pattern matching symbol only creates build rules for all the cpp files in the current directory so how can I modify that rule to include all sub directories?

Here are the most notable variables I have:

```
SRC_FILES       =   $(wildcard *.cpp) \
                    $(wildcard Logger/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES       = $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.o)
DEP_FILES       = $(OBJ_FILES:.o=.d)

DEBUG_BUILD_DIR = $(BUILD_PREFIX)/debug
DEBUG_BINARY    = $(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)/$(BINARY_NAME)
DEBUG_CFLAGS    = -DDEBUG -g
DEBUG_OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)/, $(notdir $(OBJ_FILES)))
```

The last line (DEBUG_OBJ_FILES) transforms each cpp file path to the output folder (e.g. Logger/Logger.cpp becomes build/debug/Logger.o)

Comment: You're missing a critical piece of information from your question: how is the variable `DEBUG_OBJ_FILES` set?  Without knowing that we can't help more.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

So in your makefile you're setting `DEBUG_OBJ_FILES` to the list of files without any path.  So, your source files would be `main.cpp` and `Logger/Logger.cpp`, and your object files are `build/debug/main.o` and `build/debug/Logger.o`.

Your pattern rule is this:

```
$(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
```

So when make wants to build `build/debug/Logger.o`, what will the pattern `%` match?  It matches `Logger`.  So you've defined a rule that could build `build/debug/Logger.o` from `Logger.cpp`, but you don't have a `Logger.cpp` in your codebase, you only have a `Logger/Logger.cpp`.  But make doesn't know how to build from that.

One option would be to define a new pattern rule for that:

```
$(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : Logger/%.cpp
        ...
```

And again for each subdirectory.  This will work.

Another option is to use GNU make's [VPATH facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html) to give make a list of paths to search for source files:

```
VPATH := Logger
```

(it always looks in the current directory first by default).

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Both solutions worked however I opted for the VPATH option because that also allows me to list all my source folders in a single location making the management super easy.